# On finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $(G,*)$ is a finite group, whose order is $n$. Also let $p|n$ and $p\in P$. Can you bring an example of such group which doesn't have an element of order $p$.

Sincerely,

Comment: Please [see the FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) concerning signatures in your posts. Thank you.

Comment: OK! Will take it into account next times! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ragib said, Cauchy's Theorem assures that if $p$ is a prime divisor of the order of the finite group $G$, then there is an element $g\in G$ of order $p$, hence at least $p-1$ of them. One may note that the proof of Cauchy Theorem's relies on a counting elements argument, thus it is not constructive.

In the comments, the questioner extended his question to elements of power prime order. Sylow's Theorems say that if $p^k$ is the highest power of the prime $p$ dividing the order of $G$, then there exists a subgroup $P<G$ with $|P|=p^k$ (such subgroups are called $p$-*sylows*). One can then apply the theory of $p$-grous to conclude that $G$ has subgroups of order any power $p^\ell$ with $\ell\leq k$. Again, the proof is not constructive.

Now, in order to decide about the existence of elements of order $p^k$ is enough to consider just one $p$-sylow and decide whether it needs to be cyclic (because by the Sylow's Theorems again all $p$-sylows are conjugated inside $G$, hence isomorphic one to another).

To answer (in the negative) to the general question it is enough to observe that in the permutation group on $10$ elements, a $5$-sylow has $25$ elements and one such is the subgroup 
$$
P=\langle(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)\rangle\times\langle(6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10)\rangle
$$
which is visibly non-cyclic.

Of course, one can come up with many more counterexamples, some of which much simpler than the one described above.

Answer (score 8):

One will not be able to find an example, because [Cauchy's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) ensures there certainly is such an element.

Comment: Thank you for your response. And what can we say, if we don't know that $p$ is a prime number?

Comment: Nothing. There are examples where $ n \mid o(G) $ but $n$ is not prime, and there exist no subgroups of order $n$, let alone an element with order $n.$ For example, the alternating group $A_4$ has no subgroups of order $6$, because subgroups with index $2$ must be normal and $A_4$ is a simple group. There exists elementary arguments to show $A_4$ has no subgroups of order $6$ as well.

Comment: And if $p=q^k, q\in P$, then by Sylow's theorem there is a subgroup of order $p$. Is there an example of such group which doesn't have an element of order $p$?

Comment: Could you clarify what $p$ means this time? If it is the order of the group, then yes there are groups which have no elements of order $p.$ Indeed, the only groups which have an element whose order is equal to the order of the group, are cyclic groups generated by that element.

Comment: No, here $p$ is some divisor for the order of the group and is equal to $q^k$ for some prime $q$.

Comment: @RagibZaman You are correct that there is no subgroup of order $6$ in $A_4$ but your argument is not valid since $A_4$ is not simple. The smallest non-Abelian simple group is $A_5$.

Comment: @Sebastian, you are correct. I should change the example to $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $30$ even though $ 30 \mid |A_5| $.

Answer (score 3):

**Proposition:** A positive integer *n* > 1 is prime if and only if every finite group whose order is divisible by *n* contains an element of order *n*.

*Proof:* If *n* is prime, then Cauchy's theorem guarantees an element of order *n* in any group whose order is divisible by *n*.  If *n* is not prime, then *n* must be divisible by at least two primes, so that *n* = *dpq*.  We consider three cases: (1) *p* = *q*, (2) *p* divides *q*−1, and (3) *p* < *q*.  In the first two cases we find a group of order exactly *n* with no element of order *n*, but in the third case we merely find a group whose order is divisible by *n* with no element of order *n*.  (1) If *n* is divisible by the square of a prime *p*, then *n* = *dp*<sup>2</sup> and the group C<sub>*d*</sub>×C<sub>*p*</sub>×C<sub>*p*</sub> has order divisible by (and exactly equal to) *n*, but contains no elements of order *n*.  (2) If *n* = *dpq* is divisible by a product of distinct primes *p*, *q* such that *p* divides *q*−1 but such that neither *p* nor *q* divides *d*, then the group C<sub>*d*</sub>×(C<sub>*p*</sub>⋉C<sub>*q*</sub>) has order divisible by (and exactly equal to) *n*, but contains no element of order *n*. (3) More generally, if *n* = *dpq* where *p* < *q* are primes that do not divide *d*, then the group C<sub>*d*</sub>×Sym(*q*) has order divisible by (but not equal to) *n* and has no element of order *n*.

In the third case, if *d* = 1 but *p* does not divide *q*−1, then every group of order (exactly equal to) *n* = *dpq* has an element of order *n*, so the larger group is necessary in case *d* = 1 at least (and so necessary for this simple proof that "ignores" d).

**The groups:**  I believe the properties of the example groups used are well known, but I state them explicitly here:

- C<sub>*n*</sub> is the (unique up to isomorphism) cyclic group of order *n*.  It has elements of order *k* exactly when *k* divides *n*.
- If *p*, *q* are primes with *p* dividing *q*−1 then C<sub>*p*</sub>⋉C<sub>*q*</sub> is the (unique up to isomorphism) non-abelian group of order *pq*.  It has a unique Sylow *q*-subgroup of order *q*, and it has *q* Sylow *p*-subgroups, so that every element is either the identity, an element of order *q*, or an element of order *p*.
- Sym( *q* ) is the symmetric group on *q* points and every element of order *q* is a *q*-cycle.  It has no elements of order *dq* for any *d* ≥ 2 (since their *d*th power is a *q*-cycle, they themselves must be a *q*-cycle, a contradiction), in particular, no elements of order *pq*.
- C<sub>*d*</sub> × *G* has elements of order *k* exactly when there are positive integers *i*, *j* such that *k* = *ij*, *i* divides *d*, *i* is coprime to *j*, and *j* is the order of an element of *G*.